# The value of 'g-recaptcha-response' of Google recatcha

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I use recaptcha in my page and i want to validate it with ajax, so i need these values to send them to my webservice and then send request to google. How can i get the value of `g-recaptcha-response`?

I use `Recaptcha.get_challenge();` to get challenge code but `Recaptcha.get_response();` always return `NULL`.

Comment: What recaptcha version are you using?